# C# GET method to accepts JSON as input parameter in NancyFx and validate it from POSTMAN

Tags: c#, api, postman, nancy

Friends,
I am new to NancyFx, I have created simple Module and trying to check the method with POSTMAN

Home Module below

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get("/", args => {
            return "Hello World";
        });

        Get("/Test", args => {
            return "Hello World Test";
        });

        Get("/getEmployees", x => {
            return GetEmployees(x);
        });

    }

    private object GetEmployees(dynamic x)
    {
        Employees employees = this.Bind<Employees>();
        return employees;
    }

}
```

> **IMAGES ARE ATTACHED IN THE LINK**

The POSTMAN client returning data properly for the below calls 
[Default Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1dwP.png)

[getEmployee details, Passing as JSON parameter {"name":"John"}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEMAw.png)
The name value "John" is not binding in employee class

I tried to add the Header "content-type" as "application-json" but now i am getting error message

[Content-type added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boxuG.png)

Please help me how to change the Method and PostMan input parameters to get the expected results as

{"id":0,"name":"John","department":null,"address":null}

Thank you. All your support much appreciated.

> **Found Solution - Updated below code**
>   `Get("/getEmployees/{x}", x => {
>                   return GetEmployees(x);
>               });`

POSTMAN data param sample (GET)
http://localhost:64369/getEmployees/{param}?name=John&Address=This is sample Test Address

For the POST method

```
Post("/getEmployees/{x}", x => {
            return PostEmployees(x);
        });
```

POST URL:
http://localhost:64369/getEmployees/{param}

The sample value have to be given in the POSTMAN, Go to Body, then select 'Raw' type should be Json
{
  "Name": "SChugh",
  "Address": "This is Test"
}

Comment: Try passing ?query={ “name”:”John” }

Comment: @Krishna - I tied with http://localhost:64369/getEmployees/?query={ "name":"John"} but still the value not assigned

Comment: Oh sorry you should use x= not query

Comment: @Krishna- Thank you, but still it is not working http://localhost:64369/getEmployees/?x={"name"="John"}

Comment: Try changing you parameter type from dynamic to string

Comment: @krishna - I want to pass JSON string as parameter for the getEmployees method, string will not work. Input parameter vary based on the client request. I should not restrict in the API code.

Comment: Json is string, you convert it in to object in your code or create a data binder. Either binder will handle or you handle it. But all things in url strings

Comment: The advantage of NancyFX, should understand the Client and serve based on the need. I think no need to write separate piece of code for each content type. WebAPI is fine.. But i am looking for someone response who worked in NancyFx and postman JSON data posting. Thank you